# Proof review: Modular arithmetic modulo order

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I have the following problem:
There are the Proth numbers $h\cdot 2^k+1$ with $h<2^k$ odd.
Let $p$ be an odd prime and $r := \operatorname{ord}_p(2)$ be the multiplicative order of $2$ modulo $p$.
Now I want to show that if $l$ is a natural number and $l\equiv k \pmod r$, then $h\cdot 2^k+1 \equiv 2^l+1\pmod r$.

Let $l\equiv k\pmod r \Longleftrightarrow r\mid k-l.$
Then we find a natural number $f$ with $f\cdot r = k-l$.
Then $k = f\cdot r + l$.
Now we have
$$
h\cdot 2^k + 1 =
h\cdot 2^{f\cdot r + l} +1=
h\cdot (2^r)^f\cdot 2^l + 1.
$$
And due to our choice of $r$ we have
$$
h\cdot (2^r)^f\cdot 2^l + 1 \equiv h\cdot 2^l+1 \pmod r.
$$

Did I forget something?

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: See the Theorem in the linked dupe.